# How to show info on table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

Im trying to load a array of strings in a table view but the view does not recognize the array.

I have an array called Playlists (declared as global on ThirdViewController) with objects from class Playlist. When I use it on every other table view I can access every object and use it on the table view (I'm using it on ThirdViewController), but on AddToPlaylist view I can't use it. I think I'm using correctly the cells and func for table views.

This happens when I press the button "Añadir" on player view. It should load the table view with the array info.

**Here is the project (develop branch):** [tree/develop](https://github.com/mamechapa2/musicplayer/tree/develop)

```
import UIKit

class AddToPlaylist: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    @IBOutlet weak var myTableViewPlaylist: UITableView!
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return Playlists.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "hola", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = Playlists[indexPath.row].name

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        Playlists[indexPath.row].songs.append(songName)
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "addedSong", sender: self)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myTableViewPlaylist.delegate = self
        myTableViewPlaylist.dataSource = self

        myTableViewPlaylist.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Here is the declaration of Playlists array:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation


var favorites:[String] = []
var Playlists:[Playlist] = []
var selecPlaylist = 0
var firstOpen2 = true

class ThirdViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView2: UITableView!

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //print(Playlists.count)
        return Playlists.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = Playlists[indexPath.row].name

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        selecPlaylist = indexPath.row
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myTableView2.delegate = self
        myTableView2.dataSource = self

        if firstOpen2{
            crear()
            firstOpen2 = false
        }

        myTableView2.reloadData()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func crear(){
        let pl1 = Playlist(name: "Prueba")

        pl1?.addSong(song: songs[0])
        Playlists.append(pl1!)

        let pl2 = Playlist(name: "Prueba2")

        pl2?.addSong(song: songs[1])
        Playlists.append(pl2!)
    }


}
```

Comment: Does your `numberOfRowsInSection` get called? If so, what value does it return?

Comment: Yes, numberOfRowsInSection is called and Im returning the Playlists.count.

Comment: how is your tableview created? I don't see it here and your project doesn't contain a xib

Comment: And the value of `Playlists.count` at that time is...?

Comment: Playlists.count should be 2, but if I print it says 0. I have done this the same way in another table views at this project.

Comment: Is `AddToPlaylist` being used before `Playlists` is initialized?  (Maybe use some `print` statements to track what's happening.)

Comment: appearently there is no issue in your code. you need to debug ... line by line.

Comment: I solved it 2 hours ago. It was a problem with the array. I add objects to the array on a viewDidLoad func. If I dont enter the view where the objects are created, the array is empty. I didnt see it the other day. How can I mark the question as solved?

Answer (score -2):

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "yourIdentifier") as! UITableViewCell

cell.textLabel?.text = Playlists[indexPath.row].name
return cell
```

Comment: `tableView.dequeueReusableCell` already returns `UITableViewCell`. It's pointless to force-cast to the type it already returns. This answer doesn't help in any way. When posting an answer, please explain what was wrong and how the answer fixes the issue.